# parse integer from mysql query in xcode

Tags: mysql, objective-c, integer

I would like to get an integer from mysql call as per call below, and then compare if the value is 0 or 1, I seem to have issues with the NSSTRING and NURL...please help

When I set mysql with value = 1, I still don't get an utput on NSLOG

```
 NSURL *database_flag_query;
 NSString *database_flag;



database_flag_query = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.0.20/iqkradio_stream_ip.php"]];
database_flag = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:database_flag_query encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];


if([database_flag isEqualToString: @"1"])
{NSLog(@"flag = 1");}
```

new code

```
database_flag_query = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.20/iqkradio_stream_ip.php"];
database_flag = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:database_flag_query encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(database_flag);
if([database_flag isEqualToString: @"1"])
{NSLog(@"flag is set");}
```

also here is my mysql query

```
mysql_select_db("qkradio", $con);
$result = mysql_query("select flag from iqkradio" );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['flag'];
```

Comment: Log `database_flag`. What does it show? If it is `nil`, then log `error`. Also, get rid of the `stringWithFormat`. Just use: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.20/iqkradio_stream_ip.php"];`.

Comment: it shows 1:  2013-04-13 13:48:50.913 iQkradio[56143:c07]  1

Comment: new code above, but still same problem

Comment: Perhaps there is some whitespace around the `1`. Log the `database_flag` like this: `NSLog(@"database_flag = '%@'", database_flag);`. Make sure there is nothing but the single quotes around the `1`.

Comment: I have noticed the blanked lines on my NSLOG output, 3 blank lines acctually!!

Comment: 2013-04-13 14:01:15.940 iQkradio[56294:c07] database_flag = ' 1 



'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you have some extra whitespace/newlines added to the end of the output.

You can trim that as follows:

```
database_flag = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:database_flag_query encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
if (database_flag) {
    database_flag = [database_flag stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"database_flag = '%@'", database_flag);
    if ([database_flag isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"flag is set");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```